# trying to execute a python script from react

Tags: reactjs

**Problem**

I am trying to execute a Python script from a React application using the child_process module. However, I am getting the following error:

> python.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: child_process.spawn is not a function
> at runScript                 (python.js:6:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
> at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
> at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
> at react-dom.development.js:9288:1

## Code

This is the code I am using:

```
import React from 'react';
const child_process = require('child_process');

function MyComponent(props) {
  const runScript = () => {
    const pythonProcess = child_process.spawn('python', ['D:\site\web-app\src\python\teste.py', "teste", "arg2"]);

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
      console.error(data.toString());
    });

    pythonProcess.on('close', code => {
      console.log(`Script completed with code ${code}`);
    });
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={runScript}>Run Python Script</button>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

and the very simple python script

> `import sys`
>
> `print(sys.argv)`

## **I have tried the following:**

Importing the spawn function directly

Comment: Web pages can't run arbitrary client-side executables.

Comment: You need a backend for this, you could create an express app that exposes an endpoint that runs your python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `child_process` is a part of the Node.js, or backend, runtime, along with Python, but React runs on the frontend, or web runtime. In this scenario, you may need to create a custom backend server using something like the `http` module or [express](https://npm.im/express). Create a handler at whatever URL you want on the server that, when called, runs the Python script like you have it and returns the result from the server. You can then call this from your React frontend using something like the web Fetch API and use the result.

Example -

Backend:

```
const express = require('express')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['D:\site\web-app\src\python\teste.py', "teste", "arg2"]);
    var d = '';
    var e = '';

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
      d += data;
    });

    pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
      e += data;
    });

    pythonProcess.on('close', code => {
      res.json({ data: d, error: e });
    });
});

app.listen(5000);
```

Run this using `node server.js` (or whatever you name the file). Then run your react app and add your function like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    ...
    const runScript = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000').then(res => res.json()).then(console.log);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is just an example, you may need to adjust it to your needs.